# App Info and Display over other apps showing full package name instead of app name in android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application

On Android 13 and over devices within app info and in our "Display Over Other Apps" pop up at install the name of the application shows as the full package name "com.air.advantage.ezone" instead of "Ezone". Also the application image does not display correctly. On earlier device versions its shows correctly as Ezone.

[App Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Ycv.png)
[Display Over Other Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL43P.png)

I have app labels set correctly within the manifest and have messed around with different manifest settings but cant find any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue myself, and I found a solution that might help you too. In my case, adding a label under the  tag resolved the problem completely.

```
<application
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
</application>
```

By ensuring that the  tag includes the android:label attribute with a valid label resource, the issue was resolved in my scenario.

Please make sure you have added the label under the `<application>` tag not `<activity>` tag this is the scenario I have faced.